$T_4/\langle\{b^nab^{-n}\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}\rangle$ and the real line with a loop attached to each integer point
Bowditch uses an example in his A Course on Geometric Group Theory, to explain a fact that a subgroup $G\leq F$ need not be freely generated even if $F$ is, but I cannot understand some details of it. Consider the $F_2=\langle a,b\rangle$ and the $4$-regular tree $T_4$, and let $G=\langle\{b^nab^{-n}\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}\rangle$. In this case, the covering space, $K=T_4/G$, is the real line with a loop attached to each integer point.

By Fact stated in precious section, I note that $\pi_1(T_4/G)\cong G$. But I still cannot grasp the idea how we can conclude that $K$ is the real line with a loop attached to each integer point. I'd appreciate it if someone can illustrate it and help me out.
